# prevent inline java script xss injection

Tags: xss

I have a url like this

```
http://www.example.com/?input=userinput
```

although i did xss injection filters

```
strip_tags ();
```

but look at this , i take this input and put it in a url like this

```
<a href ="http://www.example.com/?page=userinput"> </a>
```

imagine user could write this code at his user input section

```
onMouseOver%3dalert%2839793%29%2f%2f
```

This will add onMouseOver event to my url !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet. It will explain all of this in detail:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

To answer the specific topic mentioned here, you need to url encode the input before printing it in the page as a part of the url. For other data inside HTML attributes you need to apply HTML attribute encoding and possibly javascriot encoding if it's in a event handler like onclick.